# How to load django fixture with erasing unexisting objects?

Tags: django, django-models, django-fixtures

1. I had a fixture with objects 1,2 and loaded it
2. I updated fixture and now it contains objects 2,3

Question: how to load new fixture with deletion object 1? I can't truncate table, because I've related objects.

Of course I can parse the fixture and delete all objects that are not there, but maybe there is a simplier way?